# A New Hope hat: Did I just time travel?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2015

Today I find the "A New Hope" hat in my ever-growing collection. It says the award criterion is "ask, answer, or vote on December 18th", which is strange given that today is December 17th. Either I am from the future (in which case your lottery numbers are…), there's a bug, or I'm just confused.

Occam's razor might suggest the last of those, but I'd be interested in alternative suggestions. Anyone? Bueller?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159577/why-are-date-based-hats-awarded-too-early

Comment: Ah! So I have Kiribati to thank. Marvellous. Thank you!

Comment: It is Friday 00:38 in Kiribati (Christmas Island)

Comment: I just received this hat on an SE site that I haven't visited since October. Beginning to think this is actually a bug.

Comment: Also, just to point out that TwoStraws got his hat at 10:30am GMT -- is there a timezone that's +14 GMT?

Comment: Yes: Kiribati. And yes, +14 is strange – I'm guessing it's for economic reasons.

Comment: I got it also today in the morning (09 am). I live in Brazil. The time fuze here is UTC -03:00

Comment: No, you didn't time travel. That would require things to be [Timey-Wimey](https://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/timey-wimey).

Answer (score 62):

**Caching** isn't that the answer to everything?

or

**time travel**

---

Actually it's to account for all time zones and kicks in when the first community on the planet reaches the given date the hat is to be awarded.

[Why are date-based hats awarded too early?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159577/why-are-date-based-hats-awarded-too-early)

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/  (or ***magic*** )

Comment: @KevinGuan: http://shouldiblamemagic.com/?

Comment: @Bergi: [*You can't blame magic with URL. Because magic can't be blamed by URL. URL is not a tool that can be used to correctly blame magic. As I have answered in magic-and-URL questions here so many times before, the use of URL will not allow you to blame magic...*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5299236)

Comment: @KevinGuan Will unicorns work for it, then?

Comment: @jpmc26: Ask these unicorns for some [unicorn dollars](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/images/wordpress/12-million-unicorn-bucks.jpg), then you could use them to [buy some hats](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/faq).